# displaying images in JComboBox

Tags: java, jcombobox

i need to display a image in JComboBox

Answer (score 11):

Just add an Icon to the model instead of a String:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ComboBoxIcon extends JFrame
{
    JComboBox comboBox;

    public ComboBoxIcon()
    {
        Object[] items =
        {
            new ImageIcon("about16.gif"),
            new ImageIcon("add16.gif"),
            new ImageIcon("copy16.gif")
        };
        comboBox = new JComboBox( items );
        getContentPane().add( comboBox, BorderLayout.NORTH );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new ComboBoxIcon();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

Comment: I have an array of BufferedImage(), can I use that instead of items[]??

Comment: @user2277550 create ImageIcons using the BufferedImage. The combo box has a default renderer for Icons, not for images.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this example that appears to do what you want.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CustomComboBoxwithImage.htm

What you are looking for is a custom renderer for the JComboBox. A renderer is simply a JComponent, so if you can create a component (JPanel with the necessary items contained), then you can create almost any result that you can think of). You can even override the paint method if using standard JComponents are not enough for you.

Comment: The default renderer for a JComboBox supports Icons.